# Complexity class of generating all permutations

Tags: permutations, computational-complexity

What is the complexity of the following problem (i.e. to what complexity class does it belong)? Given a positive integer $n$, provide all permutations of the sequence $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.

Comment: $O(n!)$ since you have to see each permutation.

Comment: $O(n!)$ refers to the running of an algorithm (a solution to the problem). I would like to know the computational complexity of the \emph{problem}, e.g. P, NP, etc.

Comment: I think all you can say is that it has complexity class DTIME(n!). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTIME for more info

Comment: @user2520938 I don't think so because that isn't a decision problem. I'd say it is a function problem, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_problem

Comment: @ftfish Provided that it is a function problem, the article claims that "function problems can be sorted into complexity classes in the same way as decision problems."

Comment: @Serge Thanks for the remarks. The only problem might be whether the complexity classes are then well accepted/recognized...e.g. searching for "FDTIME complexity" gives "only" 268 results, though the results make some sense...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at least in

$\mbox{FDTIME}(n\cdot n!)$, since the output itself contains $n!$ sequences, each having $n$ entries

and

$\mbox{FDSPACE}(n)$, since a stack of length $n$ is enough. The output doesn't count.

They are defined in [this thread](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7022/show-that-the-multiplication-lies-in-fl).

I don't know whether this is of any use though.